# Snowflake pyspark connector exception net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing below exception while trying to connect to snowflake to pyspark:

```py
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o117.load.
: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: !200051!
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFBaseSession.getHttpClientKey(SFBaseSession.java:321)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFSession.open(SFSession.java:408)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initialize(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:104)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initializeConnection(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:79)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initConnectionWithImpl(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:116)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:96)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:172)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper.getConnector(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:209)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are behind a firewall or a proxy server. I suggest using the Snowflake connectivity diagnostic tool [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) to make sure that all Snowflake URLs are reachable. If you see any errors, then you might want to check your firewall configuration or add a proxy configuration to spark the connection.